# How to smooth an image loaded with FileReference?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, bitmap

Been trying to smooth images loaded with FileReferece with no luck. Below is the code I'm using:

```
fileRef = new FileReference();
fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileLoaded);

private function fileLoaded(e:Event):void{
    var ldr:Loader = new Loader();             
    ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void{
        var bm:Bitmap = Bitmap(e.target.content as Bitmap);
        bm.smoothing = true;
        img.load(bm)
    }); 
    ldr.loadBytes(fileRef.data);
}   

<custom:SWFLoaderAdvanced id="img"/>
```

**bm.smoothing** should've smoothened the loaded image, but for some reason it doesn't. Am I missing something here?

Note: **SWFLoaderAdvanced** automatically smoothens any image that's loaded inside it. It works perfectly with loaded images other than the ones loaded with FileReference.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the data is loaded into flash as byteArray, try this and see what happens.

your line here:

```
var bm:Bitmap = Bitmap(e.target.content as Bitmap);
```

wants to be:

```
var bm:Bitmap = new Bitmap(e.target.content as BitmapData);
```

Comment: Tried this and it throws a ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property data not found on flash.display.LoaderInfo and there is no default value.

Comment: you are correct, that was my mistake and getting mixed up with Loader classes. it should have read 'e.target.content' as listed in your example. edited to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `bm.smoothing` isn't working, perhaps it is but the effect is barely noticeable. One thing you could try is a `BlurFilter`.

```
import flash.filters.BlurFilter;
var blur:BlurFilter = new BlurFilter(1, 1, 5);
```

Where the first and second arguments are `blurX` and `blurY`, and the third is the quality. I imagine you can apply this to a `Bitmap` object, probably using this function:

```
bitmapDataObject.applyFilter();
```

That function is detailed further in the AS3 Reference; I'm not at a computer with Flash installed so I can't test exactly how this would work. You will definitely be able to apply blur effects to `Bitmap` objects though, and if you do a very slight one with high quality, it'll appear to smooth the image. Check out `BlurFilter` and `BitmapData` in the docs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. I'm pretty sure that smoothing isn't happening - it is very noticeable. Still looking for a solution.